# Same rank average but fewer impressions?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

On Google search console, for the same specific page (not site), I can see a bit difference between 2020 and 2021.

It surprises me that for the same average rank position (or even a better one), now I got thousands of impressions less than the previous year. How is this even possible?

Isn't position directly related to the number of impressions that you will get as long as the search volume is stable over time?

[image]

On the picture we can see the following:

| top queries | Impressions 2020 | Impressions 2021 | Difference | Position 2020 | Position 2021 | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| javascript window resize | 940 | 258 | 682 | 36.2 | 33.5 | 2.7 |
| window resize | 706 | 138 | 568 | 59.6 | 55.4 | 4.2 |

Comment: Where is the search volume data?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur I don't think we can see this on Google search console?
However, it wouldn't make sense for the volume of those keywords to go down as much as  73% in one year. I would say, that's definitely not possible.

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur here are the google trends for those keywords. Seems quite stable: https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=2020-01-01%202021-09-19&q=window%20resize 

Not 73% less?

Comment: Why would the search volume be stable over time?

Comment: I see a slight downward trend in the search volume chart.  Maybe not 75%, I also don't trust Google Trends to be a strong predictor.  Additionally, Google Trends can only measure Google traffic, and doesn't include Bing, DuckDucK, Yahoo, etc,

Comment: @Trebor I can't really see a strong reason for these keywords to decrease 75% on searches?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It wouldn't. For `js window resize` it has fluctuated between 1000 (low) and 3600(high) over the past several years. On average 2300. If I was to describe the basis, it appears sort of quarterly.

Answer (score 4):

There are a *ton* of reasons you might receive less impressions for a certain term over time. Nowadays a single SERP is not bound to a single exact match (or close variant) keyword. Since RankBrain and BERT, Google have become much smarter about how they serve results for a given query.

Keep in mind this is your *average* position. So if you're seeing less impressions it probably means your actual rank is *decreasing*.

If your *actual* position is roughly the same, I'd say that the decrease in impressions is likely due to an increase in new terms or a decrease in interest on the topic. Users' search history is definitely a factor here as well.

Ultimately, it's hard to say since I haven't been monitoring it for months how the overall data has been moving. Even the most subtle things matter.

The best way to tell what's important on a given SERP is to **test** and see what see what makes it go up! For this reason, I'm going to help you get started on improving the page.

### Make Sure Keyword Cannibalization is Ruled Out

Often times if a site has 2 or more pages that get impressions for the same terms, Google (in lieu of being unable to decide which to rank) will suppress both.

Essentially what they're saying is like:

> We notice that more than one of your pages are competing for the same term, but we can't rank them both. Work it out between them, and until then we'll hold them both back to be fair.

In cases of keyword cannibalization, I typically see the competing pages sitting between position 20-40.

### I'd Consider Position ~15-30 to be Within "Striking Distance"

Striking Distance keywords are those that are very actionable to get onto page 1 - they are your "Low Hanging Fruit" as the pundits say.

To a seasoned SEO, it is usually pretty clear what has to be done to in order to rank. However, the higher in position, the more ambiguous it becomes.

### Look at Everything Pages Between position 30 and 1 Do and Do it *Better*

Here's page 1 of the SERP for "JavaScript Window Resize" (In the US):

[image]

The only result(s) in the top 5 I can see getting bumped out are the one occupying position 4 - it has the least amount of links, and the least Page Authority (which I opt to look at over DA because Google Ranks *pages* not *websites*). The Stack-overflow answer probably get's the most clicks and highest time on page (there's a lot of answers).

What about page 2?

[image]

### Here's Your Strategy

- Include a section with relevant background info/docs:

  - [https://drafts.csswg.org/resize-observer-1/](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize) <--seems important
  - Address scope changes? <-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize
  - Other info like this
- Address why the user is looking for info on this, what were they likely just doing? What is their next query going to be?
- List the top situations window resize implementations get caught up with bugs. There's a good chance your reader has been pulling their hair out for awhile and is extremely ticked off.

  - The reader is either a noob (syntax errors) or an experienced developer (updated docs/specs, equivalents in other JS flavors). So perhaps organize your content by skill level - provide a way to take both groups to the answer they need quickly.
- Figure out the top things that people are looking to do with window resize and create as "copy and paste-able" (RIP Larry Tesler) boilerplate as possible examples that people can drop into their project.
- Anything else that is relevant that pages between 30 and 1 *do not* address.
- I don't see a whole lot of videos, and sometimes for "guide"/"how to" stuff adding one is seen as a big value add.
- Build 1-3 solid quality links to your new page.

Don't implement them all at once - request indexing after each new addition and and monitor to see the marginal effect. Build the links last.

Comment: Many times when I make a big update to a piece of existing content, I can sort of spot what _appears_ to be the page getting moving in the index because impressions will spike way up and average position will completely tank (and then shoot back up _hopefully higher_.

Comment: Awesome answer!! Thanks for that! 
What do you mean by "What do you mean by "Anything else that is relevant that pages between 30 and 1 do not address."? So, from page 2 and onwards on Google results? 

Regarding the idea of applying a change at a time. I've read Google can take months to update their indexed results? How often should I check for changes?

Comment: @Steve I meant like any other relevant information to the topic that the sites ranking 1-30 _do not_ cover. I didn't go looking through all of them. But if you spend a day and go through all of those pages and give them a thorough analysis...you're bound to find something!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why wouldn't I cover anything that is relevant on a topic in pages that rank between the 1st position in Google search results to the 30th?
Isn't my goal to be in their position too?